# Django Improperly Configured for View (Login)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on setting up an auth for a Django project, I created an app called users to handle all auth related operations, profiles, etc

I created a templates folder inside users app folder, inside there is two HTML files called : standard_signup.html and login.html .

Here are urls.py files for the full site and the users app:

urls.py - Full django site (the django project):

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path("accounts/",include("users.urls")),
   


]
```

urls.py - users app:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("signup/user/",views.StandardSignUp.as_view(),name="signup"),
    path("join/",views.LoginPage.as_view(),name="login-page")



]
```

All the view classes for users are obviously defined in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView 
# Create your views here.


class StandardSignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'standard_signup.html'


class LoginPage(CreateView):
    template_name = "login.html"
```

Signup works well, when I go to /accounts/signup/users/ I get the signup html template. But when I go to accounts/join/ I get this error :

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/join/
LoginPage is missing a QuerySet. Define LoginPage.model, LoginPage.queryset, or override LoginPage.get_queryset().
```

I can't find a workaround online for this error and I've been struggling for many hours with it.

Comment: This is not really a `CreateView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `LoginPage` is not really a `CreateView`, but a [**`LoginView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView). A `CreateView` will need a `form_class` attribute, or a `model` with `fields` for example. A `LoginView` does *not* create such object, but aims to log in the user.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

# …

class LoginPage(LoginView):
    template_name = "login.html"
```

For such simple views however, you can define the parameter in the `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/user/', views.StandardSignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('join/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login-page')
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I had to use CreateView in order to create a view, I was wrong according to the docs, this is my first time using Django.

Comment: @Souames: relax, everyone misreads documentation (I definitely did as well) :). It is only by doing you eventually "grasp" the exact meaning of the classes, methods, etc.